# How do I calculate the following integral $\int\frac{dx}{x^{3}(x^{2}+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I calculate the following integral
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^{3}(x^{2}+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$$
I found this result in a book
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^{3}(x^{2}+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}=\frac{-1}{2x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}-\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}+\frac{3}{2}\ln(\frac{1+\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}{x})+C$$
but I couldn't find a way to solve it

Despite trying, please help me to find a way so that I can understand how to solve it

Thanks in advance

Comment: hint, substitute $u=x^2+1$ and notice that $x^4 = (u-1)^2$.

Comment: $u=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and you get a rational function. Very often when you see a square root, just substitute that.

Comment: Another possible substitution is $u=\sinh(x)$.

Comment: @eMathHelp it is effectively tempting, but $\int\frac {dx}{\sinh(x)^3\cosh(x)^2}$ is not so much appealing. In fact we would probably subtitute back to get a rational function...

Comment: @zwim , subsequent subsitution $v=\cosh(u)$ makes the integrand rational.

Comment: @eMathHelp that's what I'm saying, ultimately this results in the combined substitution $v=\cosh(u)=\cosh(\sinh^{-1}(x))=\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

Comment: @zwim, makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts as follows

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{x^{3}(x^{2}+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}\ dx\\
=& -\int \frac{1}{2(x^2+1) \sqrt{x^{2}+1}}\ d\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)\\
\overset{ibp}=& \ -\frac{1}{2x^2\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}
-\frac32 \int \frac1x\ d\bigg( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}\bigg)\\
 \overset{ibp}= & \ -\frac{1}{2x^2\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}-\frac32 \bigg( 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}-\int \frac1{x \sqrt{x^{2}+1}}dx\bigg)\\
= & \ -\frac{1}{2x^2\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}-
\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}+\frac32 \tanh^{-1}\sqrt{x^2+1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{1}{x^{3}(x^{2}+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}dx &\stackrel{t=\frac{1}{x}}{=}-\int \frac{t^4}{\left(1+t^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} d x \\
&=\int t^3 d\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right) \\
&=\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}-3 \int \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} d t \quad \textrm{( via IBP)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Letting $x=\sinh \theta$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} d t&=\int \sinh ^2 \theta d \theta=\int \frac{\cosh 2 \theta-1}{2} d \theta =\frac{\sinh \theta}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}= \frac{1}{2}\left(t \sqrt{1+t^2}-\sinh ^{-1} t\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Putting all back yields $$
\int\frac{1}{x^{3}(x^{2}+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}dx = \frac{2}{3}\left[-\frac{x^2+1}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1}}+\sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]+C $$

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int\frac{dx}{x^{3}(x^{2}+1)\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$$ Let $x=\sinh(t)$
$$I=\int \text{csch}^3(t)\, \text{sech}^2(t)\,dt$$ Let
$t=2 \tanh^{-1}(u)$
$$I=\int\frac{\left(u^2-1\right)^4}{4 u^3 \left(u^2+1\right)^2}\,du$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{\left(u^2-1\right)^4}{4 u^3 \left(u^2+1\right)^2}=
\frac{1}{4 u^3}+\frac{4 u}{\left(u^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{u}{4}-\frac{3}{2 u}$$ and all antiderivatives are simple.

Shorter would be to use directly
$$x=\sinh \left(2 \tanh ^{-1}(u)\right)=\frac {2u}{1-u^2}$$ for the same result.